# Makefile compare string input

Tags: shell, makefile

To understand better string variables in a Makefile, I have tried to do this example :

```
KEYWORD=Nothing

test:
    $(call myFunc)

define myFunc
ifeq ($(KEYWORD), "Apple")
    echo "You have found the key"
else
    echo "Try again"
endif
endef
```

But when I'm typing

```
make test KEYWORD="Fork"
```

It prints errors

```
syntax error near unexpected token `Fork,'
`ifeq (Fork, "Apple")'
```

I have also tried :

- Put **Apple** or **'Apple'** in ifeq
- Put a space or not after **","** : **ifeq ($(KEYWORD), "Apple")**
- Run command with **KEYWORD=Fork**
- Did it **using shell** (if [ ${KEYWORD} -eq "Apple" ])

I'm running out of ideas because I don't understand how Makefille / Shell interpret the assignment **KEYWORD="Fork"**

Thanks

Comment: BTW, you should replace `$KEYWORD=Nothing` with `KEYWORD=Nothing`

Comment: Yes, wrong typing, I didn't put $ in my file, sy (edited in the post)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MadScientist identifies the problem.  Perhaps the solution you're looking for is simply evaluating the conditional earlier.  eg:

```
KEYWORD ?= NOTHING
...
ifeq ($(KEYWORD), Apple)
define myFunc
        echo "You have found the key"
endef
else
define myFunc
        echo "Try again"
endef
endif
```

Comment: It only prints Try again with command like "make test KEYWORD="......"

Comment: You need to use `KEYWORD ?= NOTHING` in the assignment, and unless you want the keyword to contain double quotes, you probably want to use `Apple` instead of `"Apple"`

Answer (score 2):

First, `$(call myfunc)` is 100% identical to writing `$(myfunc)`.  The `call` function in make merely expands a variable with some other local values (the arguments) bound first.  If you don't provide any local values, then you're just expanding the variable.

Expanding a variable just replaces the variable reference with what it expands to.  So writing:

```
FOO = bar
foo:
        echo $(FOO)
```

is 100% identical to writing:

```
foo:
        echo bar
```

So in your situation,

```
test:
        $(call myFunc)
```

is the same as:

```
test:
        $(myFunc)
```

which is the same as:

```
test:
        ifeq ($(KEYWORD), "Apple")
            echo "You have found the key"
        else
            echo "Try again"
        endif
```

which is why you get the output you did: these are not valid shell commands, but since you've expanded the variable as part of a recipe, they are sent to the shell as part of the recipe.

Comment: Thx for your answer, I've tested with the last code (without creating function and variable above) and running the command make test KEYWORD="Fork" (and without ""). It prints the same error

Comment: This doesn't show how to make it work, because you didn't ask for that: you wanted to understand variables, so this is an explanation of why you are seeing the behavior you're seeing, so you can understand what is happening and how make is interpreting your variables.  If the question is what changes are needed to make it work, you should ask that :).  To be clear there's nothing mysterious about how make interprets `KEYWORD=fork`; it works just as you expect.  The problem you had was in how you were using the variable `myFunc`.